# When the letter of recommendation will be asked for by the hiring committee?

Tags: postdocs, recommendation-letter

I have already applied for a postdoc announcement in Europe. During the online process of uploading my documents, I was asked for the name of two references as well. According to the time table of evaluation process, in the first month the committee will evaluate the applicants. It seems that up to now (one month after uploading documents) the committee have not demand letter of recommendations from my references. What is the meaning of that? Does it mean that my application is unsuccessful? Need to say, after the first month of pre-selection, they will give priority to the pre-selected applicants. Might the committee ask the letters of recommendation during the second stage?

Comment: Maybe they will ask later, maybe not at all. Maybe they are disorganized and forgot about this. Many different szenaeios can apply. Question: What would the answer matter to you?

Comment: @Thomas Actually, I am asking this question just for my Curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nobody outside the committee knows.** Maybe you are not under consideration. Maybe they ask for letters at a later point of the evaluation process. Maybe they never actually ask for letters.

I understand that applying for jobs is a high-pressure situation, but trying to infer information from noisy signal like that is, generally speaking, not useful. There are just too many variables that you (and we) have no way of knowing.